# Unix Shell script un-expected output

Tags: shell, scripting, sh, ksh

I have this KornShell (ksh) script. It is printing only `a` and `b`. I am not sure why it is printing only these two letter?

**script:**

```
#!/bin/ksh
for i in [global]
do
        echo $i
done
exit 0
```

**output:**

```
./a.sh
a
b
```

I need to understand how shell interpreting [global] word.

Comment: Where is [global] defined ? When I run when you have entered it outputs [global]

Comment: I expect to print [global], it just string

Comment: That's what I see when I run it. What OS/Shell version are you running ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the string `[global]` is treated by the shell as a glob pattern and attempts to match any files in the current directory that have a single-character name from the set of characters `{a, b, g, l, o}`. You have two files in that directory named `a` and `b` respectively. If you want `[global]` to be treated as a string, then add some quotes:

```
for i in "[global]"
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Quoting prevents globbing.

Comment: Under what version of ksh and OS did you observe this? I have run exactly what he has entered and have received [global] as the output .... @sfgroups do you have files named a and b in the current directory ?

Comment: @JamesGawron If the glob doesn't match anything, it's left as-is, so if you don't have a file named `a`, `b`, `g`, `l` or `o`, `echo [global]` will in fact print the string `[global]`. If you do, though, the pattern gets replaced with the list of matching files. This is in `bash`, but globbing (at least that particular form) works pretty much the same way in `ksh`, `csh` (shudder), `zsh`, etc... You can verify this: `mkdir x; cd x; echo [global]; touch a; echo [global]`

Comment: Verified ... I often wonder on SOF where in the world people come across these details, as I have not seen that documented anywhere in my travels (:^)

Comment: @JamesGawron: Bracket notation and the fact that a pattern that doesn't match files is left untouched is [specified and documented in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13).

Comment: @JamesGawron  this gives me the answer. I  had filename  a & b in the directory. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

This ksh script works fine in Cygwin with ksh version: *MIRBSD KSH R48 2013/08/16*.

**Ksh Script**

```
#!/bin/ksh
for i in [global]
do
    echo ${i}
done
exit 0
```

**Ksh Script Output:**

```
userr@foo:/tmp $ ksh so7.ksh
ksh so7.ksh
[global]
userr@foo:/tmp $ echo $KSH_VERSION
echo $KSH_VERSION
@(#)MIRBSD KSH R48 2013/08/16
userr@foo:/tmp $ sh so7.ksh
sh so7.ksh
[global]
```

Comment: @avaPlease42  the issue problem I had file a and b in that dir. touch a b, then run the script it will list a & b